# strtok does not returns all the tokens

Tags: c, strtok

I have the following snippet of code:

```
char *buffer2 = malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s",buffer2);
    char *command = strtok(buffer2," ");

    if (strcmp(command,"INFO") == 0)
    {
        char *file_path = strtok(NULL," ");
        if (file_path != NULL)
         {
            info(file_path);
         }
    }
```

My goal is : given a string like "CMD_NAME ARG1 ARG2" ... to tokenize the string according this format. So far so good, I have written the above code, it compiles, the program does not crash ,but the outcome is ,however, wrong in the sense that if I input the string "INFO work/file1.sf" the command is parsed properly but for the file_path the strtok function returns a NULL pointer. I have been struggling with this for hours , I have read the documentation for this function, I have searched other responses on this subject ,but none of the them were satisfactory. If you have a clue of what I'm doing wrong please help me.

Comment: @user3121023 I think that's worth an answer

Comment: @user3121023 Oh my God, you are right... I was not accounting a trivial fact. Thank you so much

Comment: Use `fgets` and add `\n` to the `strtok` separators.

Comment: Beware that if you want to handle escaped characters and quoted arguments, you will need something a bit better than `strtok` or `sscanf`.  Still, it's pretty straight-forward to roll something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following code:

```
char *buffer2 = malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
scanf("%s",buffer2);
char *command = strtok(buffer2," ");

if (strcmp(command,"INFO") == 0)
{
    char *file_path = strtok(NULL," ");
    if (file_path != NULL)
     {
        info(file_path);
     }
}
```

the expression 'sizeof(char)' is defined by the standard as 1.
Multiplying anything by 1 will not change its' value
and has no effect on the parameter passed to `malloc()`.

However, it does clutter the code, making understanding, debugging, and maintenance more difficult.

Suggest removing that expression.

when calling `scanf()`

1. always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.
2. when using the "%s" format specifier..
   must use a max input characters modifier, so the user cannot overrun the input `buffer2`
3. the "%s" format specifier will stop inputting when encountering any 'white space'
   The call to `strtok()` will not find anything but the whole input line.
   because the input will have stopped before inputting any spaces
   because a `space` is one of the 'white space' characters.

Suggest the following code:

```
#define BUFFER_LEN (1024)
char *buffer2 = NULL;
if( NULL == (buffer2 = malloc( BUFFER_LEN ) ) )
{ // then malloc failed
    perror( "malloc for 1024 bytes failed")
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, malloc successful

if( !fgets( buffer2, BUFFER_LEN, stdin ) )
{// then, fgets failed
    perror( "fgets from stdin failed");
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE )''
}

// implied else, fgets successful

char *command = NULL;

if( NULL != (command = strtok(buffer2," \n") ) )
{
    if (strcmp(command,"INFO") == 0)
    {
        char *file_path = NULL;
        if( NULL != (file_path = strtok(NULL," \n") ) )
        {
            info(file_path);
        }
    }
}
```